# Hibernate @OneToMany doesn't link child and parent on save

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, spring-data, one-to-many

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "parent")
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@SequenceGenerator(name = "parentSequence", sequenceName = "parent_id_seq",
        allocationSize = 1)
public class ParentDto implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "parentSequence")
    private Long id;
    
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent")
    private List<Child> children;
}


@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
@SequenceGenerator(name="childSequence", sequenceName = "child_id_seq", allocationSize=1)
@Table(name = "child")
public class Child{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "childSequence")
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id", nullable = false)
    private Parent parent;
}
```

I have the next request to save mapped to property `request` (ids should be generated by DB)

```
{
    "parent": {
       "name": "Bob",
       "children": [{
            "name": "Bob2"
       }]
    }
}
```

Executing `parentDao.save(request);`
and trying to get child executing `childDao.findAll();` which returns empty array.
When executing `parentDao.findAll()` - receiving parent which contains child object with `id=null` and `parent=null`.
Also while performing `parentDao.save(request)` with updated data getting such exception

> Unable to find ChildDto with id 1; nested exception is
> javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find ChildDto
> with id 1

If I update ParentDto with

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private List<Child> children;
```

receive such exception

> Caused by: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity
> passed to persist: ChildDto

Comment: Show us the code you save the data.

Comment: I have 
public interface ParentDao extends JpaRepository<ParentDto, Long> {
}
and call it's method parentDao.save() 
The same dao for child